p-tree click on whole node
Please can anybody give me the idea, How to fix p-tree component that I can click on whole node, not only on toggle icon.
I found that I can expanded root node by click like:
@HostListener("click") onClick() {  this.usersService.treeData[0].expanded=true; 
but how to define on which child element user clicked ?
Please advise...
p.s. Angular 14 PrimeNG.
I tried to use style to catch it like:
 const elements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("p-tree"); elements.forEach( (element: any) => { this.renderer.listen(element, "click", event => { console.log('CLICK', element.nativeElement.label);
but i can't define which child node was clicked.

I was also looking for a solution but I didn't found an onNodeClick in the emitters. See https://primeng.org/tree#api.tree.emitters. I think we need to use the selectionMode="single" and use selectionChange event even if we don't want to use selection

Looking at the source, pTree tracks the nodes by "key", which is effectively a hyphen-delimited list of array indexes from the tree's root node. This value is exposed to the DOM starting in v15, but we can achieve something similar in earlier versions as well, including the OP's target version of 14.
v14 and prior
When in doubt, you can usually fall back to invoking the click method of a corresponding button. The source tells us the toggle button can be identified by the class p-tree-toggler and its container by the attribute [role="treeitem"]. Note that this will cause (onNodeExpand) and (onNodeCollapse)` to emit.


@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(event: { target: HTMLElement }) {
  // use Element#closest() to search up the DOM tree for the container element
  const treeItem = event.target.closest('[role="treeitem"]');
  // use querySelector to search back down to the toggler
  const toggler = treeItem?.querySelector?.<HTMLElement>('.p-tree-toggler');
  // manually invoke the click method
  toggler?.click?.();
}



As a directive:


@Directive({
  selector: 'p-tree[clickAnywhere]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PTreeClickAnywhereDirective {
  @Input() clickAnywhere = true;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: { target: HTMLElement }) {
    if (this.clickAnywhere === false) return;
    // nothing to do if the user clicked the toggler directly
    if (event.target.classList.contains('p-tree-toggler')) return;
    if (event.target.classList.contains('p-tree-toggler-icon')) return;

    const treeItem = event.target.closest('[role="treeitem"]');
    const toggler = treeItem?.querySelector?.<HTMLElement>('.p-tree-toggler');
    toggler?.click?.();
  }
}



Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tree-demo-sxz78m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
v15+
Thanks to the key being exposed to the DOM, we can use the pTree's own getNodeWithKey() method to track down the TreeNode value and modify it directly.
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
 onClick(event: { target: HTMLElement }) {
     const key = event.target.closest<HTMLElement>('[role="treeitem"]')?.dataset?.id;
     if (key) {
         const treeNode = this.pTree.getNodeWithKey(treeItem.dataset.id, this.pTree.value);
         treeNode.expanded = !treeNode.expanded;
      }
  }

As a directive:
@Directive({
  selector: 'p-tree[clickAnywhere]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PTreeClickAnywhereDirective {
  @Input() clickAnywhere = true;
  @Input() emitEvents = false;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: { target: HTMLElement }) {
    if (this.clickAnywhere === false) return;

    const treeItem = event.target.closest<HTMLElement>('[role="treeitem"]');
    if (treeItem) {
      if (this.emitEvents || !treeItem?.dataset?.id) { // fallback to click invocation for <=14
        treeItem?.querySelector?.<HTMLElement>('.p-tree-toggler')?.click?.();
      } else {
        const treeNode = this.pTree.getNodeWithKey(
          treeItem.dataset.id,
          this.pTree.value
        );
        treeNode.expanded = !treeNode.expanded;
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(private pTree: Tree) {}
}

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kdzhru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fptree-click-anywhere.directive.ts
Preventing text selection
You may a want to consider adding something like this to your root styles.[s]css to prevent text from being selected when the user clicks repeatedly:
.p-treenode-label {
    user-select: none;
}


<p-tree #tree [value]="nodes">
  <ng-template pTemplate="node" let-node>
    <div [attr.id]="node.key" class="tree-node-clickable">
      <span>{{node.label}}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-tree>
   

 @ViewChild('tree') tree: ElementRef;
 nodes = [];
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
 onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    
        const nodeId = target.closest('.tree-node-clickable')?.getAttribute('id');
    
        if (nodeId) {
          const clickedNode = this.findNodeById(nodeId);
          if (clickedNode) {
            console.log(clickedNode);
          }
        }
    }
    
 findNodeById(id: string): any {
        return this.findNode(this.nodes, id);
 }
    
 findNode(nodes: any[], id: string): any {
       for (const node of nodes) {
          if (node.key === id) {
            return node;
          }
          if (node.children) {
            const foundNode = this.findNode(node.children, id);
            if (foundNode) {
              return foundNode;
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
}


Try using (nodeclick) to handle clicks on node:
<p-tree [value]="treeData" (nodeClick)="onNodeClick($event)"></p-tree>

Possible changes to make in component.ts file:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-tree',
  templateUrl: './my-tree.component.html',
})
export class MyTreeComponent {
  treeData: TreeNode[] = [
    {
      label: 'Root',
      data: 'Root Data',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Child 1',
          data: 'Child 1 Data',
          children: [],
        },
        {
          label: 'Child 2',
          data: 'Child 2 Data',
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  onNodeClick(event: any) {
    const clickedNode = event.node;
    console.log('Clicked node:', clickedNode);
    
    // You can expand/collapse the node or perform any other action
    clickedNode.expanded = !clickedNode.expanded; // Toggle expansion
  }
}

